# Nativescript Swipe can't get direction

Tags: xml, swipe, nativescript

I have this files to detect the direction of swipe.

xml:

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" swipe="onSwipe">
    <Label id='swiped' text='test' />
</StackLayout>
```

js:

```
function onSwipe(args) { 
    page = args.object;
    var sb = page.getViewById("swiped");
    sb.text  = 'direction'+ args.direction;
}
exports.onSwipe = onSwipe;
```

I am not sure why I can't get args.direction.

Comment: Can you give some more information about which version of {N} you are using and on what device or emulator you are testing. With the latest official version 1.4.2, I am getting the direction when I am swiping, using the code you provided.

Comment: im using 1.4.0 ..does this version does not support the direction yet? hmm..

Comment: Actually, there was a problem with taking the object in 1.4.0, so this might be the problem. I would suggest upgrading to 1.4.2.

Comment: Hmm.. its strange, im not getting the direction.. ..Im using an iphone4s simulator..

Comment: I just changed my previous comment :)

Comment: Thank you :) it works. I updated {N} version. :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable the cell scrolling in the XML declaration: swipeCells="true"

```
<lv:RadListView items="{{ dataItems }}" swipeCells="true" itemSwipeProgressEnded="{{ onSwipeEnded }}">
```

For future reference here is a tutorial by Telerik about getting the x and y directions: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/ListView/listview-features-swipe-to-execute